# Print Partial Page and Show Partial Page in New Window Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

1. How do you Print a Partial Page?
2. How do you Show a Partial Page in New Window? Then User Prints.

Note: The partial page is in an IFrame.

Comment: what do you mean by partial page? And if "partial page" is loaded inside IFrame, you can use javascript:window.open('partialpage.aspx', 'Partial Page); to popup new window

Comment: Yes Id like to print the contents in the iframe with opening a new window and without opening a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some limitations when printing the contents of an IFrame. JavaScript security policies will prevent you from printing something if its in a different domain. This is the method I've used for years to print specific content on a page.

First you need a simple print function in JavaScript. This is the one I use

```
    print = function(str) {
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.open("text/html", "replace");
    WinPrint.document.write('<html><head><title>Printing</title></head><body>');
    WinPrint.document.write(str);
    WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
};
```

Then you need to pull the HTML from the iframe

```
   getIFrameContent = function(IFrameID) {
    return document.getElementById(IFrameID).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
};
```

Then a simple function to wrap the whole thing to make it easier

```
printIFrame = function(IFrameID) {
    print(getIFrameContent(IFrameID));
};
```

Once you have all that you can call the printIFrame method and simply send in the ID of the IFrame.

Method 2:
Open the Iframe in a new window and print that window.

```
 var printIFrame2 = function (IFrameID) {
        var URL = document.getElementById(IFrameID).getAttribute("src");
        var WinPrint = window.open(URL, 'WinPrint', 'left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    };
```

Comment: Great i will give that a try.

Comment: I have it hooked up and Did a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript from a menu item in code behind. it call it but I get the error on the first code block print = function(str) {.... Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action

Comment: ok, now i have it working, it only prints the text though, how do you print the everything in the IFrame, or Div, or Whatever control?

Comment: I added a second way to print the Iframe. The second way opens the iframe in a new window and calls window.print. That should get you everything that is in the iframe including pictures and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know else to post code unless i ask a question. So for Cris is this what you menat is to put javascript in main page like so?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    print = function (str) {
        var WinPrint = Window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.open("");
        WinPrint.document.write('');
        WinPrint.document.write(str);
        WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    };
    getIFrameContent = function (IFrameID) {
        return document.getElementById(IFrameID).contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    };
    printIFrame = function (IFrameID) {
        print(getIFrameContent(IFrameID));
    };

</script>
```

Then call from code behind like so...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "key", "printIFrame(" & MyIFrame.ID & ");", True)
```

Comment: That will work if you need to print the iframe from a server side call. Another way would be to add a button or hyperlink on the page that calls the script like so  `<a href="javascript:printIFrame('IframeID');">Print IFrame</a>`

Answer (score 0):

This is tested by me:

Printable portion of the page:

```
<div id="printArea">
     <h1>I am going to print from here</h1>
     <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Print Button:

```
<a href="#" onClick="printDiv();return false;">Print</a>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function printDiv() {
    var w = window.open('', '','width=auto,height=auto,resizeable,scrollbars');
    w.document.write($("#printArea").html());
    w.document.close();
    javascript:w.print();
    w.close();
    return false;
}
```